# How to read a custom claims value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, claims

In my application, I have used to store user access in the claims when users log in to the system. So when the user input the user name and the password,  return the access types and values then stores in the claims. This is how I did that in the account controller.

```
public void SignInUser(string username, string userRole, string userid, bool isPersistent, string UserLevel,string AdminPannel, 
            string MasterPannel, string Add_Supplier, string Update_Supplier, string Add_Employee, string Update_Employee,string View_PenReq ,
             string View_ServReq,string View_ReqHis, string View_Inspect, string Authriz_Req, string Sus_CashPay, string Fin_Report)
        {
            // Initialization.    
            var claims = new List<Claim>();
            try
            {
                // Setting    
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username));
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
                claims.Add(new Claim("UserId", userid));
                claims.Add(new Claim("UserLevel", UserLevel));
                claims.Add(new Claim("AdminPannel", AdminPannel));
                claims.Add(new Claim("MasterPannel", MasterPannel));
                claims.Add(new Claim("Add_Supplier", Add_Supplier));
                claims.Add(new Claim("Update_Supplier", Update_Supplier));
                claims.Add(new Claim("Add_Employee", Add_Employee));
                claims.Add(new Claim("Update_Employee", Update_Employee));
                claims.Add(new Claim("View_PenReq", View_PenReq));
                claims.Add(new Claim("View_ServReq", View_ServReq));
                claims.Add(new Claim("View_ReqHis", View_ReqHis));
                claims.Add(new Claim("View_Inspect", View_Inspect));
                claims.Add(new Claim("Authriz_Req", Authriz_Req));
                claims.Add(new Claim("Sus_CashPay", Sus_CashPay));
                claims.Add(new Claim("Fin_Report", Fin_Report));
                

                var claimIdenties = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
                var authenticationManager = ctx.Authentication;
                // Sign In.    
                authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, claimIdenties);
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                
                var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimsPrincipal;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Info    
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Now in the view, I want to check if the **PendingRequest** is true in the claims, Pending request pannel will show to the user. I managed to read the data in the username claim by doing this code

```
@User.Identity.Name
```

But for reading this, It doesn't work. Here is the view code in the pannel. Thanks

```
<li class="nav-item">
      <a href="@Url.Action("PendingRequests_Hod","PendingRequest")" class="nav-link">
      <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
      <p>Pending Requests</p>
      </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get a desired claim like this:

```
var req = (User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "View_PenReq").FirstOrDefault();
string reqValue = req.Value;
```